# The value for "Shared" column is not displayed correctly in shell namespace extension

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

I use shell namespace extension to create a virtual folder on windows 7.
I want to add columns to this virtual folder so it can display the virtual files's details. However, the value for "Shared" cannot display correctly.
Here is the related code:

```
else if (IsEqualPropertyKey(*pkey, PKEY_IsShared))
    {
        if (cch)
        {
            hr = StringCchCopy(pszRet, cch, L"");
        }
        else
        {
            pv->vt = VT_BOOL;

            BOOL isShared;
            GetIsShared(pidl, isShared);

            VARIANT_BOOL shared;

            if (isShared) shared = VARIANT_TRUE;//I add breakpoint here, it works
            else shared = VARIANT_FALSE;

            pv->pboolVal = &shared;

            hr = pv->pboolVal ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
    }
```

Above code is located in the function `IFACEMETHODIMP GetDetailsEx(PCUITEMID_CHILD pidl, const PROPERTYKEY *pkey, VARIANT *pv);` which is a windows provided interface.
[image]
I add breakpoints to the above code, it turns out when the variable `isShared` is `true`, the variable `shared` does become `VARIANT_TRUE`.
However, when I check the value it displays in the UI, it displays `no` for all objects:
[image]
As you can see, in the column of "Shared", all the value is "no".
Actually, the top 3 files are shared and they should be "yes".
when the debugger reaches the breakpoint in the above code, the value is `VARIANT_TRUE` for these three files.
Here is the WINDOWS definition for `PKEY_IsSahred`

```
//  Name:     System.IsShared -- PKEY_IsShared
 //  Type:     Boolean -- VT_BOOL
//  FormatID: {EF884C5B-2BFE-41BB-AAE5-76EEDF4F9902}, 100
//
//  Is this item shared?  This only checks for ACLs that are not inherited.
DEFINE_PROPERTYKEY(PKEY_IsShared, 0xEF884C5B, 0x2BFE, 0x41BB, 0xAA, 0xE5, 0x76, 0xEE, 0xDF, 0x4F, 0x99, 0x02, 100);
```

I also tried to edit the above code like:

```
if (isShared) shared = (VARIANT_BOOL)1;
else shared = (VARIANT_BOOL)0;
```

It doesnw ork.
If I replace `pv->pboolVal = &shared;` with `pv->boolVal= shared;`, it will work like:
[image]
Only display "Yes" for the top three files.

If I use `VARIANT_TRUE` and `VARIANT_FALSE` and `pv->boolVal`,it still only display "Yes".

```
pv->vt = VT_BOOL;

            BOOL isShared;
            GetIsShared(pidl, isShared);

            VARIANT_BOOL shared;

            if (isShared)
            {
                shared = VARIANT_TRUE;
                pv->boolVal = shared;
            }
            else
            {
                shared = VARIANT_FALSE;
                pv->boolVal= shared;
            }           

            hr = pv->boolVal ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
```

-----Working Update-------------------

```
if (isShared)
            {
                shared = VARIANT_TRUE;
                pv->boolVal = shared;
            }
            else
            {
                shared = VARIANT_FALSE;
                pv->boolVal = shared;
            }           

            hr = S_OK;
```

This one works for me!

Comment: Why do you use `pboolVal`? you must use `boolVal`

Comment: @SimonMourier Can you see my updates? When I use boolVal, it displays the second screenshot. ( Only display with "Yes")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `pboolVal` member here and assigning a pointer to something on the stack is certainly not the correct thing to do. The type would have to be `VT_BYREF|VT_BOOL` to use `pboolVal` but in this case there is no point to do that and you have no memory you can point to.

Just use `boolVal` and VARIANT_TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Can you see my updates? When I use boolVal, it displays the second screenshot. ( Only display with "Yes")

Comment: `(VARIANT_BOOL)1` is wrong, use `VARIANT_TRUE`. Anyway, I assume it works correctly because Explorer in a normal folder will also sometimes display Yes, No and nothing ( https://imgur.com/a/dHK4TaL ).

Comment: If I use VARIANT_TRUE and VARIANT_FALSE and pv->boolVal,it still only display "Yes".

Comment: Are you returning S_OK even when it is not shared?

Comment: Oh, Thanks, that's the problem. When I return S_OK for both of them, it works !